# python-glob2 example is not clear

Tags: python

According to the documentation example at https://github.com/miracle2k/python-glob2, the developer writes the source code -

```
from glob2 import Globber

class VirtualStorageGlobber(Globber):
    def __init__(self, storage):
        self.storage = storage
    def listdir(self, path):
        # Must raise os.error if path is not a directory
        return self.storage.listdir(path)
    def exists(self, path):
        return self.storage.exists(path)
    def isdir(self, path):
        # Used only for trailing slash syntax (``foo/``).
        return self.storage.isdir(path)
    def islink(self, path):
        # Used only for recursive glob (``**``).
        return self.storage.islink(path)

globber = VirtualStorageGlobber(sftp_storage)
globber.glob('/var/www/**/*.js')
```

I have difficulty in understanding the line `globber = VirtualStorageGlobber(sftp_storage)`. What is sftp_storage here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is either

1. an instance of [django-storages](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages) sftp storage class [`storages.backends.SFTPStorage`](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/sftpstorage.py)
2. meant to be a storage object you invent yourself that implements `listdir`, `exists`, `isdir`, `islink` and supports SFTP

Since this is an example it is not entirely clear and probably doesn't matter as long as you implement the methods mentioned above.

Comment: so, this should also work `globber=VirtualStorageGlobber(os)` ? Because then, os.listdir(path) is implemented

Comment: No since `os` does not implement `exists`. You can see that `VirtualStorageGlobber` calls `self.storage.exists(path)` and if `self.storage` is set to `os` then this will result in `os.exists(path)` which is not defined.